# combining multiple htaccess rules

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a htaccess rule that remove `.php` extension:

```
 `RewriteEngine On
  ErrorDocument 403 "Page not exist"
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]`
```

the htaccess rule below redirects to `stream.php` file:

```
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/musicbox/stream/?tag=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`
```

Both rule works individually, but when combined,the rule placed below does not work.

Comment: Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 0):

You have the same conditions twice:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Which means:

- `!-f`: File `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` doesn't exist.
- `!-d`: Directory `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` doesn't exist.

If both are true and the next one (in the first set of rules) is also true:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
```

Then the next rule will do a `301` redirect ([`R=301`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r)) and stop processing rules ([`L`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)).

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Actually, maybe there's a missing `^` in there. It should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Anyway, that means that the second set of conditions and the subsequent rule won't be reached:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/musicbox/stream/?tag=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Probably you don't need those first `R=301` and `L` flag. I think this is how it should look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 403 "Page not exist"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /core/musicbox/stream/?tag=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```